# AngularJS and ui-router: wrong routes behaviour after refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm developing an application with AngujarJS and ui-router and I'm having a problem loading the routes. To facilitate the explanation I will delete parts of the code. My rotes file looks like this:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, 
$locationProvider) {

$stateProvider
.state('dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboard',
  templateUrl : 'pages/dashboard.html',
  controller  : 'DashController'
})
.state('dashboard.vendas', {
  url: '/vendas',
  templateUrl : 'pages/vendas.html',
  controller  : 'vendasController'
})
;

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
      });
});
```

I load this route **/dashboard** after the user login. On this route, I load, among other things, an http method that returns the companies that the user will have access to, through the factory below:

```
app.factory("factoryEmpresas", 
function($http,urlBase,isAuthenticated) {
return {
    getEmpresas: function() {
        return $http({
            url: urlBase.getUrl() + '/empresas',
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'X-Token': isAuthenticated.getJWT()
            }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {   
            return response.data;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            return response;
        });

    }
}
});
```

When accessing the route **/vendas** (which is related to the state dashboard.vendas), I make another http call using a variable that is in the factoryEmpresas return as follows:

```
app.factory("factoryVendas", 
function($http,urlBase,isAuthenticated) {
return {
    getVendas: function(id_empresa) {
        return $http({
            url: urlBase.getUrl() + '/vendas?id_empresa=' + id_empresa,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'X-Token': isAuthenticated.getJWT()
            }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {   
            return response.data;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            return response;
        });
    }
}
});
```

Everything works perfectly, until the user decides to refresh (F5) when on the route **/vendas**. At that moment the loading of the two routes **/dashboad** and **/vendas** is triggered. However, when making the http call at factoryVendas, the factoryDashboard has not yet returned the getEmpresas function. Thus, the variable "empresa_id" is not filled with the value that it should, thus resulting in an undefined call in place of "empresa_id".

The question I ask is, how can I make factorySales wait for the factoryDashboard to return so that I can make the call with the variable duly filled in?

Any help will be welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: Check out resolves https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

If your factory returns a promise, you can get your data resolved before your controller loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like vendas has a direct dependency on empresa. Would it make sense to make `empresaId` part of the route parameters for accessing vendas? That way the information needed to load the page would always be accessible (from `$stateParams`), even on reload

```js
.state('dashboard.vendas', {
  url: '/:empresaId/vendas/',
  templateUrl : 'pages/vendas.html',
  controller  : 'vendasController'
});
```

The other thing you could do is define load order by creating a resolve on the parent that the child consumes. Then uirouter knows it needs to wait for the parent resolve before attempting to load the child.

```js
$stateProvider
.state('dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboard',
  templateUrl : 'pages/dashboard.html',
  controller  : 'DashController',
  resolve: {
      Empresas: function(factoryEmpresas) {
          return factoryEmpresas.getEmpresas();
      }
  }
})
.state('dashboard.vendas', {
  url: '/vendas',
  templateUrl : 'pages/vendas.html',
  controller  : 'vendasController',
  resolve: {
      Vendas: function(Empresas, factoryVendas) {
          var id_empresa = Empresas[0].id; // just kind of guessing here
          return factoryVendas.getVendas(id_empresa);
      }
  }
})
```

`Vendas` and `Empresas` can be injected into their respective controllers.

While this would work I'd actually discourage this method because now your user is waiting around more for content to appear. Studies have shown its better to show your users incremental progress, your app will feel faster. I try to avoid resolves when possible and have initialization logic in my controller. That way, the page loads immediately and fills in as data becomes available.

Comment: Ramirez Thanks for the answer.
The second option with "solve" solved my problem.
But, as you mentioned, there is a delay in displaying the page.
Could you give me an example of how to handle the first option in the controller? How do I pass this parameter when changing the state once I transition between routes with the tag "ui-sref" in HTML?

Comment: You can use `ui-sref="dashboard.vendas({empresaId: 'empresa_id_goes_here'})"` and then access it in your controller with `$stateParams.empresaId`

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. I tried to implement but I couldn't.

I don't know how to set the company_id value in the "ui-sref" tag.

I was also unable to access the variable empresa_id of the route /vendas in the controller DashBoard.

Sorry, but don't have much experience with AngularJS.

Comment: I made a small plunkr - https://plnkr.co/edit/IdY4vqSm5jnVyizf. Click to run and preview, also open preview in separate window so you can see url changes

Comment: Crhistian Ramirez, sorry for the delay in returning.
I was working on another project.

His example was very clear and it worked perfectly for me.

Thank you very much for your attention!